# Android GridView onitemdownclick

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using a GridView following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

In my app, each image in the grid acts as a button that takes the user to another screen. That's all fine and dandy.

What I'm having trouble with is finding some way to darken the image once a user clicks down, and then lighten it again when the user releases it. `onItemClickListener` doesn't have an `onItemDownClick` function built in. What would be the best/most pain free way to create this functionality, or a similar function?

Comment: Refer to a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) in the docs (also commonly named 'selector' because of the related xml tag). You'll want to set on the `GridView` using the `android:listSelector` attribute, or `setSelector(int)` in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of CLICK use the TOUCH events (which have down and up and a lot of other stuff) and for the darkening and lightening I would use a semi opaque colored box that you show/hide depending on the situation.